# SQL DB to DB Copy

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hey I am using MS SQL Server . Is there any SQL command which will copy the entire db (including the sp , views , functions) to another blank db . 
table data can be transfered to another db tables, But How about the entire db  ?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: Oracle DB, MySql, ....

Comment: SQL is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @Berger I am using  MS SQL server , I want to  copy a database to another database in the same sql instance. Is that possible ?

Comment: @EdHeal MS SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Copy All tables with Data in Another Database

 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspCreateCopyTables]-- GOALTEST,GOAL     
        -- parameters for the stored procedure here    
        @toDatabase VARCHAR(100)    
        ,@fromDatabase VARCHAR(100)    
    AS    
    BEGIN    
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from    
        SET NOCOUNT ON;    

        DECLARE @fullTableList VARCHAR(8000);    
        DECLARE @idx INT;    
        DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(8000);    
        DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(500);    
        DECLARE @ParameterDefinition NVARCHAR(100);    

        -- this  query gives the list of table name existing in the database.    
        SELECT @fullTableList = ISNULL(@fullTableList + ',' + TABLE_NAME, TABLE_NAME)    
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES    
        WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';    

        SELECT @idx = 1    

        /* this section splits the table name from comma separated string and copies that table name from      
            one database to another database*/    
        IF LEN(@fullTableList) > 1    
            OR @fullTableList IS NOT NULL    
            WHILE @idx != 0    
            BEGIN    
                SET @idx = CHARINDEX(',', @fullTableList)    

                IF @idx != 0    
                    SET @tableName = LEFT(@fullTableList, @idx - 1)    
                ELSE    
                    SET @tableName = @fullTableList    

                IF (LEN(@tableName) > 0)    
                    SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT  * INTO [' + @toDatabase + '].[dbo].[' + @tableName + '] FROM [' + @fromDatabase + '].[dbo].[' + @tableName + ']'    

                EXEC (@SQLQuery)    

                SET @fullTableList = RIGHT(@fullTableList, LEN(@fullTableList) - @idx)    

                IF LEN(@fullTableList) = 0    
                    BREAK    
            END    
    END    
    GO
```

Comment: I have to copy all scheme not only the table data . schema including views, sp, functions .. apple to apple database copy !

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

- [Backup & Restore:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-sql-server-databases) Backup the whole database and then restore it on the other instance. Tasks -> Backup.
- Copy the database files (.mdf, .ldf files), and then [attach it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database) in the other instance.
- Use [Generate scripts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078(v=sql.105).aspx) wizard to generate the whole database objects (schema and data) in .sql files, then run these files on the other instances.

Comment: That means we cant implement this using sql statement such as stored procedure / sql quries . Thanks anyway !

Comment: @sreejesh Yes sure you can implement these in sql statments like stored procedure or in a sql job. You can also make sql jobs to sync the data between the two databases.